# Jquery accordion

Tags: jquery

I have set up jQuery accordion in my page as

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#MGH").accordion('activate', 1);
    });
```

Now inside this div I have one button onclick of which I will validate and show some alert.
My problem is whenever I am clicking ok in the alert this accordion is getting fired.How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to avoid page re-loading, because while you are clicking on the button, page gets re-loaded and the accordion gets fired. You can overcome this by declaring retrun false while you click on the button.
Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/#event.stopPropagation.28.29)